# Executing AutoIT script from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, automation, command-line-arguments, autoit

I am successfully running a Autoit script from command prompt.

```
"Z:\AutoItScripts\test.au3" "parameter1"
```

I need to do same from VB.net. Please help how can I do this.

Comment: Can you just `shell` it? [Shell Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

eg

```
Shell("Z:\AutoItScripts\test.au3 parameter1")
```